# Migrating from CamelTestSupport to AbstractCamelTestNGSpringContextTests

Tags: apache-camel, testng, spring-test

I've been using `Apache Camel` since 3-4 months on `Spring 4.0.7.RELEASE`
I have several `Camel 2.14.0 TestNG` tests based on extending `CamelTestSupport`, in which I use some `MockEndpoint`s.
I configured my routes by overriding the `createRouteBuilder()` method.

Now I would need also to inject some Spring beans in one of them, by `@Autowired` annotation.
By reading what is said at http://camel.apache.org/spring-testing.html, I understood that I've to extend `AbstractCamelTestNGSpringContextTests` now, which supports `@Autowired`, `@DirtiesContext`, and `@ContextConfiguration`.

While I understood that all `MockEndpoint`s are no more accessible by `getMockEndpoint()` method, but by using `@EndpointInject` annotation, it is not clear to me is how I can express my routes, because `createRouteBuilder(`) is not more available.

I saw that is possible to define producers and consumers by using annotations, but I cannot manage to understand how routes can be designed.

Many thanks to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to the solution given [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@camel.apache.org/msg45048.html), you may use the TestNG helper `CamelSpringTestSupport` in combination with `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`if you want to initialize an annotated based Spring configuration context without the need of an additional XML Spring configuration file.

Camel configuration bean class using Spring annotations:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig extends SingleRouteCamelConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Override
    public RouteBuilder route() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:test").to("mock:direct:end");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The TestNG test class extends `CamelSpringTestSupport` and the Spring configuration `MyConfig` is initialized with `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`:

```
public class TestNGTest extends org.apache.camel.testng.CamelSpringTestSupport {
    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:direct:end")
    protected MockEndpoint errorEndpoint;

    @Produce(uri = "direct:test")
    protected ProducerTemplate testProducer;

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);
    }      

    @DirtiesContext
    @Test
    public void testRoute() throws InterruptedException {
        // use templates and endpoints
    }
}
```